# When to use "async" instead of returning a new Task.Run task?

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5

So here I have a function

```
static bool Login(SignupData sd)
{
   bool success=false;
   /*
      Perform login-related actions here
   */
}
```

And there is another function

```
static Task<bool> LoginAsync(SignupData sd)
{
   return Task.Run<bool>(()=>Login(sd));
}
```

Now, I've come across a rather different implementation of this pattern, where you would add the `async` keyword to a function which returns `Task<TResult>` (so that it ends up looking like: `async Task<TResult> LoginAsync(SignupData sd)`). In this case, even if you return `TResult` instead of a `Task<TResult>`, the program still compiles.

My question here is, which implementation should be prefered?

```
static Task<bool> LoginAsync(SignupData sd)
{
   return Task.Run<bool>(()=>Login(sd));
}
```

OR this one?

```
async static Task<bool> LoginAsync(SignupData sd)
{
    bool success=Login(sd);
    return success;
}
```

Comment: move your question to code review stack exchange

Comment: @KevinAvignon Please check the Code Review rules before suggesting to post questions there.

Comment: You should be getting compiler warning for the second method. And none of the implementations is good. If you can't provide truly async method, then just don't provide it. The caller can always do `Task.Run`.

Comment: @KevinAvignon This is not an acceptable question for Code Review, as it contains stub code or a small portion of a piece of code. Please see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) before recommending Code Review.

Comment: Your second example returns `sd` which is a `SignupData`, not a `bool` - did you mean to `return success;`?

Comment: The second one really should be `return await Task.Run<bool>(()=>Login(sd));`.  At the very least you should have an `await` in a method marked with `async`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot yes.. that is what I meant. Duly edited.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be doing either. Asynchronous methods are useful if they can prevent threads from being blocked. In your case, your method doesn't avoid that, it always blocks a thread.

How to handle long blocking calls depends on the application. For UI applications, you want to use `Task.Run` to make sure you don't block the UI thread. For e.g. web applications, you *don't* want to use `Task.Run`, you want to just use the thread you've got already to prevent two threads from being used where one suffices.

Your asynchronous method cannot reliably know what works best for the caller, so shouldn't indicate through its API that it knows best. You should just have your synchronous method and let the caller decide.

---

That said, I would recommend looking for a way to create a `LoginAsync` implementation that's really asynchronous. If it loads data from a database, for instance, open the connection using `OpenAsync`, retrieve data using `ExecuteReaderAsync`. If it connects to a web service, connect using the asynchronous methods for whatever protocol you're using. If it logs in some other way, do whatever you need to make *that* asynchronous.

If you're taking that approach, the `async` and `await` keywords make perfect sense and can make such an implementation very easy to create.

Comment: How is this an argument *against* `async` (or tasks, ignoring the choice of Run) as a composition?

Comment: @user2864740 Either I don't understand your question, or I don't see how it relates to my answer. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Is `IHttpClient { Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(Uri path); }` a valid interface?

Comment: +1 from me. I think it's the first time I see someone advocating for using `Task.Run` on UI apps. I've been criticised in the past (not in Stack Overflow) for saying the same :-)

Comment: @user2864740 yes it is, and you can make your implementation using `async` or not (depending on if you use `await` or other means of creating a `Task`), and you let your caller call your `GetAsync` method using `await` or not, as they choose

Comment: @user2864740 Ah, I see where you're going with that. In that case, if it doesn't contain any asynchronous code in its implementation, I would say "don't use `Task.Run` and don't use `async`/`await`": I would say "use `Task.FromResult`". But that's likely a different scenario: that's when the implementor is *forced* to return a `Task` for compatibility reasons. That's not the impression I get from this question.

Comment: @Jcl To be clear: I hope you were saying to use `Task.Run` for CPU-intensive operations. If most of the time is waiting for disk or network I/O, there are better ways, of course. :)

Comment: @hvd yes, of course... I was basically seeing someone code some cpu-bound processes in a desktop app (winforms) using async/await, and his UI was no-less than jumpy and laggy... yet he insisted that async/await was the "way to go", even on winforms. To be honest, I never cared to demonstrate, just nodded and smiled :-)

Answer (score 0):

While HVD is correct, I will dive into async in an attempt to describe its intended use.

The async keyword, and the accompanying await keyword is a shortcut method of implementing non blocking code patterns within your application. While it plays along perfectly with the rest of the Task Parallel Library (TPL), it isn't usually used quite the same. It's beauty is in the elegance of how the compiler weaves in the asynchronicity, and allows it to be handled without explicitly spinning off separate threads, which may or may not be what you want.

For Example, let's look at some code:

```
async static Task<bool> DoStuffAsync()
{
    var otherAsyncResult = doOtherStuffAsync();

    return await otherAsyncResult
}
```

See the await keyword? It says, return to the caller, continue on until we have the result you need. Don't block, don't use a new thread, but basically return with a promise of a result when ready (A Task). The calling code can then carry on and not worry about the result until later when we have it.

Usually this ends up requiring that your code becomes non-blocking the whole way down (async all the way as it were), and often this is a difficult transition to understand. However, if you can it is incredibly powerful.

The better way to handle your code would be to make the synchronous code call the async one, and wait on it. That way you would be async as much as possible. It is always best to force that level as high as possible in your application, all the way to the UI if possible.

Hope that made sense. The TPL is a huge topic, and Async/Await really adds some interesting ways of structuring your code.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx